# How do I set the Program type?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm getting "ERROR: Targets with a unique build environment cannot be built in an installed engine.". This happens even when I build a new blank C++ project and make one specific change.

Inside of MyProject.Target.cs, I change the Type to Program, like so.

```
Type = TargetType.Program;
```

After changing that, anytime I try to build, clean, or generate visual studio files I get the error. The error doesn’t happen if I use TargetType.Game. However, I need to use Program so that I can build as a DLL using “bShouldCompileAsDLL = true;“ as documented on (https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/BuildAsALibrary/).

I’m running Unreal Engine 4.27. I need to set the type to Program instead.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can build it to dll with Game target.
Set both of these envs:
LinkType = TargetLinkType.Monolithic;
bShouldCompileAsDLL = true;